# Z-index of scrollbar thumb in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to style the scrollbar in firefox to achieve the look of the scrollbar in OS X Lion.
here's my code for stylish:

```
scrollbarbutton {-moz-appearance: none !important}

scrollbar, scrollcorner { -moz-appearance: none !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
}

scrollbar[orient='vertical'] { border-left: 0; -moz-transform:translateX(10px)}
scrollbar[orient='horizontal'] { border-top: 0; }

thumb { -moz-appearance: none !important;
border-color: red !important;
background: transparent;
opacity: .5;
border-style: solid;
}

thumb:hover, thumb:active {opacity: 1}

thumb[orient='vertical'] {
-moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/mxzFF.png) 15 0 15 0 fill;
border-width: 8px 0 8px 0;
-moz-transform:translateX(-10px);
z-index: 10000
}
```

However, the z-index setting does nothing, the page content overlays the scrollbar thumb.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last css block to this:

```
thumb[orient='vertical'] { 
-moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/mxzFF.png) 15 0 15 0 fill; 
border-width: 8px 0 8px 0; 
-moz-transform:translateX(-10px); 
position: relative;
z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that fixes the static position, but: I can't properly click the thumb, only the rightmost part of the thumb can be clicked. And when I moe it with my mouse, only the rightmost part moves, the rest stays static, and updates when I release the mouse. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/2eniY.png

Comment: Hmm that actually doesn't seem to do anything.